# Использование нескольких @OneToOne аннотаций Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня есть 3 сущности: `Customer`, `User` и `VerificationEmail`.

Между ними зависимость `@OneToOne` (bidirectional). Зависимость `@OneToOne` работает только с `Customer -- User`. Теперь я пытаюсь добавить зависимость `Customer -- VerificationEmail`, но я фейлюсь. Идея такова, что id VerificationEmail должен быть зависим от id Customer. То есть при сохранении объекта `Customer`, id у `User`, `VerificationEmail` должен наследоваться от `Customer`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Customer.java:**

```java
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your surname")
    private String surname;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn (name="customer_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    VerificationEmail verificationEmail;
}
```

**User.java:**

```java
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    private String password;

    @OneToOne
    private Customer customer;
}
```

**VerificationEmail:**

```java
@Table(name = "email_verif")
public class VerificationEmail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "email_verif", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @Column
    private String token;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**Customer.java:**

```
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your surname")
    private String surname;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="verificationEmailId")
    private VerificationEmail verificationEmail;

}
```

**User.java:**

```
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Customer customer;

}
```

**VerificationEmail:**

```
@Table(name = "email_verif")
public class VerificationEmail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String token;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "verificationEmail")
    private Customer customer;

}
```

Comment: Не работает(( Выдает ошибку связанную с mappedBy:   `AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: startApp.logReg.entities.User.customer, referenced property unknown: startApp.logReg.entities.Customer.customer`

Comment: @Antonio112009 поправил. Проверьте

Comment: Вроде сработало. Сейчас проверю, что работает

Comment: программа требует использование `cascade = cascade=CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: @Antonio112009 Вам такое не подходит?

Comment: Впринцепи подошло)